# Indent/Outdent issue with CKEditor component in XPages

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino

I have a problem with CKEditor component and its indent/outdent functionality.

I create a document with a RichText CKeditor component : I add indented and outdented text.
 When I re-open the document in read mode : it's OK.
When i edit my document : all indents and outdents are lost !

When I look to the HTML code, I see that indent/oudent correspond to "margin-left" attribute. These attributes seems to be removed when CKEditor is opened in Edit mode.

What about you ? Is it an issue ? May I forget something ?

Thank you.

Comment: Happens here also. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (which we are looking to address in future releases) and is due to the [Active Content Filtering](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_forms_xpages_security.html) being set on the Rich Text Editor by default.
You can override this setting by setting htmlFilter="identity" but you are opening up your application and server to malicious attack - not to be advised.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, solution and advice ! I will use it on an intranet application so malicious attack are really limited.

Comment: I wouldn't advice using that setting under any circumstance and that includes secure networks like an intranet. I'd advise keeping the defaults that are there with the rich text editor.

Comment: Agree. There's no ambiguity for me : you advice me no to use this solution and keep defaults.